# \vspace not working with negative values

Tags: spacing, lists, vspace

I have a list(enumerate) which is followed by a rule. I want to make the rule move closer to the list. I usually do this with \vspace but for some reason, it doesn't work this time. The rule moves only if the value inside vspace is positive. For negative values it stays fixed.

For 30mm:

[image]

For anything negative:

[image]

This is the relevant part:

```
\begin{enumerate}[font=\itshape,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,noitemsep]
\item \textit{\en{Last item}}.
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{-80mm}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4mm}
```

test document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\en[1]{[#1]}
\begin{document}

aaa

\vspace{80mm}

bbb

\begin{enumerate}[font=\itshape,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,noitemsep]
\item \textit{\en{Last item}}.
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{-80mm}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4mm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: You have not mentioned it but you appear to be using `enumitem` package syntax. You have given no indication of the definition of `\en`.   I added  a test document to your question but it shows the expected rule 8cm above the end of the enumeration. Please edit the example so that it shows your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may looking for something like this:

[image]
(red lines indicate text area borders)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[font=\itshape,leftmargin=*,
                  topsep=0pt,noitemsep,
                  after=\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}] % <---
\item   A
\item   B
\item   \dots
\item   Last item
\end{enumerate}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4mm}

\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```